# Javascript file upload in 2 steps

Tags: javascript, upload

I know there are lots of topics explaining the file upload via javascript. But my problem is something else with it.

I have my file upload with plain JS, which works fine but my problem is, I don't want the files get straight uploaded after choosing them from the form. Because the form has got other input field and I want to upload everything to the server after hitting the save button via ajax. I don't want to refresh the page either therefore everything should go through ajax.

Long story short:
There are 3 input(text) fields, an input(file) field and a save button in my form.
After hitting the save button the form calls a JS function and this has to handle the data(texts and files) and send it via ajax to server.

Hope I could explain the problem.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="field1">
<input type="text" name="field2">
<input type="text" name="field3">
<input type="file" name="file" multiple id="myFile" onchange="uploadPicture()">
</form>
```

And the JS

```
function uploadPicture() {
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('myFile').files.length[i]) {
formData.append('files[]', file);
....
and in here I send the formData via ajax to my server, which works fine.
```

Now my problem is not sending the data straight to the server but saving them temporary and then after hitting the save button sending everything to server...

I wonder if there is a way (trick) to having the files saved between uploading and sending.

Hope it is more clear now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declaration of your `formData` variable into the outer scope, only add the files in `uploadPicture` and then use `formData` in the click-handler on your save button.

I hope that helps.